# How to trigger server component revalidation after API call in NextJs 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a server component ("/") that directly queries my DB with Drizzle. If the user has at least one file then the UI looks different. If I'm on a different page and call this route below I want the "/" route to be reloaded the next time it's visited. This code does not accomplish that. How do I get the home page ("/") to reload after this route is called? I've tried many different approaches in the docs and have not been able to figure out why it's not working.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { chats } from "@/lib/db/schema";
import { eq } from "drizzle-orm";
import { deleteFromS3 } from "@/lib/s3";
import { deleteFromPinecone } from "@/lib/pinecone";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function DELETE(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { chatId } = await req.json();

    // delete from DB
    const file_keys = await db
      .delete(chats)
      .where(eq(chats.id, chatId))
      .returning({ file_key: chats.fileKey });

    const file_key = file_keys[0].file_key;

    // delete from S3
    await deleteFromS3(file_key);

    // delete from Pinecone
    await deleteFromPinecone(file_key);

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "successfully deleted" },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "something went wrong" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  } finally {
    revalidatePath("/");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**revalidatePath** dont **reload** or **refetch** data on route "/". it just invalidate cache on that route.
also base on nextjs document on [**this link**](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) :

**revalidatePath** only invalidates the cache when the included path is next visited. This means calling revalidatePath with a dynamic route segment will not immediately trigger many revalidations at once. **The invalidation only happens when the path is next visited**.

you can revalidating **all data** by do this :

```html
revalidatePath('/', 'layout')
```